# React-Redux: Action isn't properly being triggered

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I'm trying to learn the MERN stack, and I'm going through [this tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-RfqbbiTGgA77tGO426V3hRF9iE). I'm getting stuck in Ep. 7. The issue I *think* I'm having is my `ADD_ITEM` action is never triggered, and so the state is never updated, and I have to reload the page in order to see any items added. The `DELETE_ITEM` action works properly, so I suspect there may be an issue with the `ADD_ITEM` action being called from a form in a modal, but I'm unsure.

Picture of my Redux DevTools after refreshing the page, deleting 2 items, and trying to add 1:

[image: Picture of my Redux DevTools after refreshing the page, deleting 2 items, and trying to add 1]

#### `itemReducer.js`

```js
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM, ITEMS_LOADING } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log(action.type);
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_ITEMS: 
            return { ...state, items: action.payload, loading: false };
        case ADD_ITEM:
          return { ...state, items: [action.payload, ...state] };
        case DELETE_ITEM:
          return { ...state,
          items: state.items.filter(item => item._id !== action.payload) 
        };
        case ITEMS_LOADING:
          return {
            ...state,
            loading: true
          };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

#### `ItemModal.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addItem } from '../actions/itemActions';

class ItemModal extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    name: ''
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newItem = {
      name: this.state.name
    }

    this.props.addItem(newItem);

    this.toggle();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Button
          color="dark"
          style={{marginBotton: '2rem'}}
          onClick={this.toggle}
        >Add Item</Button>

        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modal}
          toggle={this.toggle}
        >
          <ModalHeader
            toggle={this.toggle}
          >
            Add To Shopping List
          </ModalHeader>

          <ModalBody>
            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="item">Item</Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  id="item"
                  placeholder="Add shopping item"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </FormGroup>
              <Button
                  color="dark"
                  style={{marginTop: '2rem'}}
                  block
                >Submit</Button>
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item: state.item
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addItem })(ItemModal);
```

**itemActions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM, ITEMS_LOADING } from './types';

export const getItems = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setItemsLoading());
    axios.get('/api/items').then(res => dispatch({
      type: GET_ITEMS,
      payload: res.data
    }))
};

export const deleteItem = (id) => dispatch => {
  axios.delete(`/api/items/${id}`).then(res => dispatch({
    type: DELETE_ITEM,
    payload: id
  }))
};

export const addItem = (item) => dispatch => {
  axios.post('/api/items', item).then(res => dispatch({
    type: ADD_ITEM,
    payload: res.data
  }))
};

export const setItemsLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: ITEMS_LOADING
  };
};
```

Comment: More of a general thing: that style or redux (and react btw.) - and your tutorial - are heavily outdated and will lead to you writing 2-3 times the code required for modern redux. For redux, please follow the official tutorial https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index
For React, you should probably get another tutorial that uses function components with hooks instead of class components.

Comment: Apart from that, the code looks on first read like it should be working. Are you maybe getting an error from the API? In that case, axios would throw an error and you would never get to a point where the action is dispatched. Look into your browser's network tab and console.